# Замер скорости запросов в aiohttp

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

У меня есть 1000 запросов которые я выполняю "параллельно" через aiohttp.Как мне замерить скорость ответа на каждый запрос? Или может есть какой другой способ отправки большого кол-ва запросов с замером скорости?

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    async with session.get(url) as response:
    # if response.ok:
       # print(response.headers)

        return await response.text()

async def main():
    urls = [f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{i}' for i in range(1000)]
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config]) as session:
         for url in urls:
         tasks.append(fetch(session, url))
         htmls = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Запоминаете время (time.clock()) перед выполнением get. После await response.text() опять получаете время и вычисляете разность с временем старта.

Comment: Отправка get запроса осуществляется массово, 1000 запросов "одновременно", те запросы которые не влезли в поток остаются в очереди на отправку, и отправляются по мере освобождения очереди, вся трудность в том, что я не могу определить начало отправки запроса.

Comment: Посмотрел aiohttp. В нем есть трассировка всех событий. Через нее можно отследить прохождение любых стадий запроса, а значит и сохранить/посчитать время. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/tracing_reference.html

Comment: Да спасибо помогло!